# Keycloak with mod_auth_openidc, retriving code and id_token

Tags: java, apache, single-sign-on, keycloak, mod-auth-openidc

I'm trying to configure Keycloak with mod_auth_openidc.  I'm using Apache 2.4 and simple Java servlets/html pages.  I have Keycloak authenticating a user and redirecting to the protected resource.
Now, I would like to get access to the user profile.  I'm assuming that I have to extract the "code" from the URL query string and then exchange it for the id_token by calling one of the Keycloak APIs. Is that correct? 
I'm not sure how to get this "code".  I see the code in the URL that hits my OIDCRedirectURI.  But I'm not sure how to get to it.  If my OIDCRedirectURI is a servlet, even though I see the redirect to the servlet, the doGet method isn't being hit so there is no way for me to get to the request and access the query parameters.  I believe I'm doing something wrong.  Could you help me figure out how to get the code and ultimately get the id_token?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the "code" and don't need to do it in your protected apps because `mod_auth_openidc` exchange it to ID token instead of you apps (It's a `mod_auth_openidc` job). If you want to access to the user profile in the ID token, you can find them in the HTTP request headers. `mod_auth_openidc` expands the claims into the HTTP request headers automatically with `OIDC_CLAIM_` prefix in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  But i don't see any of the OIDC_CLAIM_ tokens in the headers.  I only see cookie mod_auth_openidc_session=3aa025d7-1d48-a94f-b0f6-093523dce0c8

Comment: I also tried using Keycloak with a Tomcat adapter (even though i lean towards Apache).  I'm able to protect my resource(s) and login to Keycloak, but then i don't see any tokens or expanded user attributes in the header.  There is also no "code" to use to call the user_info endpoint.  The documentation isn't clear on how to obtain the user profile...

Comment: Did you check the http request headers in your back-end application which is protected by `mod_auth_openidc`? You only see these values in your protected app since `mod_auth_openidc` proxies the request and add headers. Also please check the `mod_auth_openidc` config if you disabled this feature. See https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/blob/v2.3.7/auth_openidc.conf#L667

Comment: Keycloak Java Adapters don't add them in the request header. If you use the keycloak adapter, you can get them using Keycloak Security Context in your Java app. Please refer to the following document.
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#security-context

Comment: Ok.  The Tomcat adapter does work using the KeycloakPrincipal right from the request. Thank you for the tip! But mod_auth_openidc doesn't work.  The servlet which mod_auth_openidc protects iterates over the request.getHeaderNames() but i see nothing related to OIDC except for cookie mod_auth_openidc_session=0e62bb80-0e37-0440-b934-6a2bc2fc97ab.  I have OIDCPassClaimsAs headers  in my apache config.  What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Some Apache security modules silently drop out headers with underscores...

- First make sure OIDCPassClaimsAs parameter is set to "headers" or "both" in the Apache configuration file.
- Then change OIDC claims prefix to "OIDC-" via OIDCClaimPrefix

All the claims should appear in the request headers. Except for the access token because its prefix is hardcoded in mod_auth_openidc code (in current version)